# How do I fix my Button not working in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm struggling to get mu button that says "Time Travel here!" to work and prompt the question. The only other things I want to add to my code is a list of more cases for the switch so it will have more years and add designs. This is for my class and It is very confusing to me. I've used W3 schools, youtube, everything. I cannot find the problem. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body style="background-color:SandyBrown;">
    <script src="script.js">
    </script>
  <div id="question"></div>
    <h1 style="color:DarkSlateGray;font-family:monospace;text-align:center;">Oh what a year that was!<h1>
            <p style="color:DarkSlateGray;font-family:monospace;text-align:center;">If you are seeing this in the year 2020, you know what we all went through this year.
                There was everything from a gloabl pandemic, forest fires, presidental elections, everything. We all likely faced individual
                struggles as well. But do you were wish you could see what another year was like?
            <br>
          <br>
          <br>
      
          Let's take a blast to the past</p>
        <button style="text-align:center"; onclick="qone()">Question</button>
     <script >
       function qone() {
 var text;
 var year = prompt("How was your 2020?");
 switch(year) {
  case "Great":
    text = "That makes one of us...";
    break;
  case "Bad":
    text = "That makes two of us...";
    break;
  case "No comment":
    text = "Understood";
    break;
  default:
    text = "I Understand";
  }
   document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = text;
}
     </script>
        
<br>
<br>
<form style="color:DarkSlateGray;font-family:monospace;text-align:center;">

<label for=“year”>What year do you want to go to? You can go back anywhere from 1 to 100 years ago!</label>
<br>

<body>

<div id="qtwo"></div>

<button style="text-align:center"; onclick="qtwo()">Time Travel here!</button>

<script>
var qtwo = "0";
switch(qtwo) {
  case 2019:
  alert("Scientists release first-ever image of black hole.");
  break;
  case 2018:
  alert("The United States Leaves the Iran Nuclear Deal.");
  break;
  
document.getElementById("Time Travel here!").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>

<script src="script.js">

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no `qtwo()` function, only a variable.

Comment: the `qone` code directly above is doing essentially what you want, compare it with your `qtwo` code.

Comment: I don't actually see your function for onclick. Unless it's in your .js file.
Friendly tip, if using Chrome, press control+shift+i, this brings up the developer console. You can view errors from there. Maybe show us the error you're getting, and then paste it here.

Comment: You never actually define `qtwo`

Answer (score 0):

1. you never defined a function called qtwo
2. returning false in onClick will prevent page reloads

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>repl.it</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body style="background-color:SandyBrown;">
  <script src="script.js">
  </script>
  <div id="question"></div>
  <h1 style="color:DarkSlateGray;font-family:monospace;text-align:center;">Oh what a year that was!<h1>
      <p style="color:DarkSlateGray;font-family:monospace;text-align:center;">If you are seeing this in the year 2020,
        you know what we all went through this year.
        There was everything from a gloabl pandemic, forest fires, presidental elections, everything. We all likely
        faced individual
        struggles as well. But do you were wish you could see what another year was like?
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>

        Let's take a blast to the past</p>
      <button style="text-align:center" ; onclick="qone(); return false;"> Question </button>
      <script>
        function qone() {
          var text;
          var year = prompt("How was your 2020?");
          switch (year) {
            case "Great":
              text = "That makes one of us...";
              break;
            case "Bad":
              text = "That makes two of us...";
              break;
            case "No comment":
              text = "Understood";
              break;
            default:
              text = "I Understand";
          }
          document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = text;
        }

        function qtwo() {
          var text = "";
          var numyrs = prompt("How many years do you want to go back in time?");
          console.log(numyrs);
          switch (numyrs) {
            case "2019":
              text = "Scientists release first-ever image of black hole."
              break;
            case "2018":
              text = "The United States Leaves the Iran Nuclear Deal."
              break;
            default:
              text = "";
              break;
          }
          document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = text;
        }
      </script>

      <br>
      <br>
      <form style="color:DarkSlateGray;font-family:monospace;text-align:center;">

        <label for=“year”>What year do you want to go to? You can go back anywhere from 1 to 100 years ago!</label>
        <br>

        <body>

          <div id="qtwo"></div>

          <button style="text-align:center"; onclick="qtwo(); return false;">Time Travel here!</button>



          <script src="script.js">

          </script>
        </body>

</html>
```

I also cleaned it up to make it easier to read.

Comment: Thank you so much. So the button works, asks the question, but the return value does not pop up anywhere on the screen. If its like the other button, It should appear at the top and its not there. Any ideas? Also thank you again, you are such a great help.

Comment: In my testing the text displayed at the top of the page where the other answer displayed. I would recommend testing it by copying the text into an html file on your desktop.

Comment: I just tried it on JSFiddle and it said "404 page does not exist". I'm so lost I cant find any errors in the code